# PyQt5 deactivate AutoLoadImages from QWebView will override my css style

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebview

I work on a simple markdown note taker editor which automatically translates the markdown text into html that a QWebView widget render.

So I basically have this **QWebView** object called *self.html* that render the Html code.

I want to **not show the img tag src** when there's one but **only show its alternative text**. I manage to find a way to deactivate the image upload with this instruction :

```
self.html = QWebView()    
self.html.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)
```

It work, but the **alternative text is not showing**.  In addition to this, My **QWebView** has a custom CSS style sheet set like this :

```
self.html.settings().setUserStyleSheetUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(PATH+style))
```

And in the CSS sheet :

code, tt

```
...
{

  margin: 0 2px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;

  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;

  font-family: Consolas, 'Liberation Mono', Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #333333;
  }

...
```

Now the problem with the CSS style, is that when I **deactivate** the **auto load images** setting, the font of **code** tag is still correct, but the **background-color** disappear! Now when I reactivate the auto load images setting to true, the background-color is there.

---

To resume my problems...

My solution was to deactivate the AutoLoadImages setting from the QWebView. But when I do that

1. Alternative text is not showing like I would like
2. CSS style seem to be override or not completely load

Answer (score 0):

So I find a solution. Instead of using the **QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages** attribute, I simply put in the CSS sheet the following :

```
img {
  display: none; }
```

However, the alternative text is not showing, but that should does the trick for now.